# Correct way to disable submit form inputs for PDF

Tags: java, pdf, firefox-addon, itext, adobe-reader

I'm trying to disable submit form inputs for pdf document.
I'm doing it so : 
`PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out, '\0', false);`

Yeah, it works but i hate this annoying dialog `This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader.  The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available.  Please contact the author for the original version of this document.`
when i open pdf.

How to disable showing up this dialog?
itext version 2.1.7.
Tried to open with chrome and firefox (adobe read plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Just need to remove user rights and enable form flattening.
`PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(dao.getFile(id));
reader.removeUsageRights();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);`